# Ionic, ошибка TypeError: Cannot read property 'imgList' of undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic, ionicframework

Код из класса:

```
export class WinsPage {

  public imgList: any;


  public loadGallery():void{
    let options ={
      maximumImagesCount: 20,
      width: 500,
      height: 500,
      quality: 75
    };
    this.imagePicker.getPictures(options).then(function (result) {
      for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        this.imgList = [{id: result[i], title: result[i]}];
      }
    });
}
```

Код страницы где хочу обработать и получить из imgList данные:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title>Мои победы</ion-title>
      <ion-buttons end>
        <button ion-button icon-only (click)="loadGallery()">
          <ion-icon name="ios-add-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
        </button>
      </ion-buttons>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row responsive-sm><!-- responsive-sm = test -->
      <ion-col col-4 *ngFor="let item of imgList">
        <img src="{{item.id}}" (click)="loadWin(item.id)" />
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>

</ion-content>
```

Не грузит в img ссылки на картинки и в консоли возвращает ошибку:
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'imgList' of undefined
imgList же объявлен. Пробовал менять на public imgList: [] и public imgList: any[]=[];
Всё равно ошибка

Answer (score 0):

В силу того что только начал изучать typescript, не правильно обрабатывал this в обратной функции (кажется так называется). Заменил function на => в imagePicker.getPictures на

```
this.imagePicker.getPictures(options).then((result) => {....
```

И случилось чудо)